# How to configure BrowserSync if index.html is inside the src folder?

Tags: angular, browser-sync

So far, I've always used this project structure

```
project/
|
+---src/
|   |
|   +---app/
|
+---node_modules/
|
+---index.html
+---package.json
|
...
```

which worked just fine, but seems the general approach is to have `index.html` inside the `src` folder. If I do that, I run into problems setting up BrowserSync.

For example, with my `bs-config.js` set up as

```
module.exports = {
   "port": 3000,
   "browser": "chrome"
};
```

and loading the page

```
localhost:3000/src/index.html
```

I get

> Cannot GET /src/index.html

If I try

```
localhost:3000/index.html
```

instead, the page is loading, but the libraries from `node_modules` can not be found (404). Here's my `ìndex.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>App</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="../node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <kma-app>Loading...</kma-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

So the question is, what do I need to change in `bs-config.js` and/or `index.html` to get this to work?

Answer (score 3):

A better approach is to use `startPath`,

```
{
  "port": 3000,
  "startPath": "src/index.html",
  "browser": "chrome"
}
```

That way, no other path has to be adjusted.

Comment: After messing with this for hours and learning more than I ever wanted to know about lite-server and Browsersynch (like bs-config.js versus bs-config.json, etc., etc.), I got my index.html into a new folder and got its loading page, but lite-server could no longer find the @angular files to load the app. I tried setting new paths in systemjs.config and got no results.  Someone needs to write a complete and specific answer / tutorial about solving this problem. I'm forced by time to live with source files that are not in src.

Answer (score 1):

Browser sync is not (yet) capable of serving SPAs (single page applications). You will run into problems if you are going to use HTML5 routing. Read [here](https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/204).

For Angular2 application development a better solution would be to use ['lite-server'](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server). This is build upon browser sync with the possibility of using it in an SPA environment.

You should add this to your bs-config:

```
{
  "server": { "baseDir": "./src" }
}
```

And start the server like:

```
lite-server -c ./bs-config.js
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, but the problem (404 for files from `node_modules` remains unfortunately.

Comment: either change the source of the node_modules in the `index.html` to `./../node_modules/.....` or `/node_modules/.....`